# Create @ToLowerCase annotation to convert String value to lower case

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

We have SpringBoot application.
For our pojo's we want to create a custom @ToLowerCase annotation which converts the field variable value to lower case.

Eg:

```
@Data
Employee {
 private String name;

 @ToLowerCase
 private String emailId;
 private String gender;
 private String phoneNumber;
}
```

So my custom @ToLowerCase annotation should convert emailId to lower case.
We want to use this annotation on all kind of Pojos, whether it is rest request pojo or JPA entity pojo.

I have gone through posts on many forums but didn't get any appropriate solution for same.

Is it possible to create such annotation in Spring Boot? If yes then how?
Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: @Data is from project lombok and has nothing to do with spring or spring-boot

Comment: When you want to change your case ? while setting or getting ?

Comment: @Yogesh Prajapati while setting I want to change case.

Comment: Check if Jackson serializer/deserializee will work for you https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-serialize-deserialize-converter.html

Comment: Please follow https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotation-bean-pre-processor

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom converter: **ToLowerCaseConverter**.

```java
    public class ToLowerCaseConverter extends StdConverter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(String value) {
        if (value == null){
            return null;
        }
        return value.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
```

After create a new annotation: **ToLowerCase**. It works for both incoming and outgoing Strings (@JsonDeserialize/@JsonSerialize).

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(converter = ToLowerCaseConverter.class)
@JsonDeserialize(converter = ToLowerCaseConverter.class)
public @interface ToLowerCase {
}
```

Finally, your example will work as intended:

```java
@Data
Employee {

 @ToLowerCase
 private String emailId;
}
```